# Can a person in the USA fly with an expired driving license?

Tags: air-travel, usa, paperwork

The company I work for has asked me to attend a training class on the other side of the country.

However my situation is my drivers license expired a few days ago. I do however have a separate printed email stating that the license has been renewed.

This drivers license is my only ID that shows both my name & photo.

Is it possible to be able to board a flight with the expired drivers license and the printed email showing that it was renewed?

Comment: Anecdote:  I've flown successfully with a drivers license that had a hole punched through the expiration date.  I was waiting for my new California license and they void your old out-of-state one.  Just project confidence - On the outbound flight I asked if it was allowed and the screener was pretty skeptical.  Coming back, I just presented it and said "It's punched because I just moved and am awaiting the new license" and had no problems.

Comment: If you have one of the upgraded driver's licenses with encoded data, I don't think you will have a problem with TSA regardless of expiration. Their web page doesn't mention the license needing to be current. https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification Now, with, Avis and Hertz, not so good.

Comment: A TSA screener, while pointing out to me that my license would expire in two weeks, told me that you can fly on an expired license for up to one year. Whether all screeners know that, or whether this guy was actually correct, I don't know.

Comment: @rogerl I was told the same thing by a TSA screener

Comment: Thanks all for answers and comments. Turns out as expected, I had no problems flying with the expired license. At one point the agent cared more about that I looked like on my photo (than that the license was expired), so she asked me to remove my cap. None of them said anything about it being expired.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus "Adult passengers 18 and over must show valid identification": *valid* generally implies *not expired.*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That would be at the discretion of the security screeners. They have methods of verifying your identity even if you have no ID at all (some people forget their wallet). If you have a passport, bring that. Otherwise I would expect an expired license will not prevent you from being boarded. As a matter of law, an expired license only affects your right to drive. Your identity does not "expire".

Comment: Second this.  There are examples of people who flew with no ID at all.  Allow lots of extra time at boarding.

Comment: ' As a matter of law, an expired license only affects your right to drive. Your identity does not "expire". ' -- this is false. Rules differ, but an expired ID is not always accepted as proof of ID.

Comment: I'd like to know what happens if your license becomes invalid because of driving offences. If a passport expires after ten years and becomes unusable, then it makes sense that a driving license expires afer ten years and becomes unusable. But what if you got caught speeding several times after two years?

Answer (score 4):

The TSA person said to me that it was ok to use up to a year after expiration. She wanted to let me know that my license expired in case I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

I have flown for years using my 4 plus years expired ID and my passports. I do however have a current one which I usually leave at home. 
As long as you haven't drastically changed in appearance or attempted to change your appearance ie... fake mustache, beard, hair pieces, fake nose,  altered chin structure, fake eye inserts, and anything else... then you should be fine.