# What do you do if your driver's license was stolen a week before a domestic US flight?

Tags: usa, airports, us-citizens, airport-security, tsa

Normally to get past the security checkpoint you need to show the TSA agent your boarding pass and a valid picture ID. But what happens if your wallet was stolen a week before your scheduled flight? You might be able to get a temporary ID (eg. a black and white printout) but would that be an acceptable picture ID?

Maybe you could file a police report about the stolen wallet but would that even make a difference in this scenario?

edit: let's assume the US state is Texas since I guess not all US states issue temporary ID's.

Comment: Were all your state-issued photo IDs stolen with your wallet ? Do you have a passport ?

Comment: Keeping in mind that this is a contrived scenario lol...  let's say that yes, all state-issued photo IDs were in the wallet (most people only have one anyway, I imagine) and that the victim doesn't have a passport (it's not like you need one for domestic trips).

Comment: You don't *need* to tell us why you're asking... but now I'm curious! Hope you're not thinking of stealing someone' driving license to stop them boarding a crucial flight? `;-)`

Comment: 2 options: 1) go to airport and hope tsa let's you through without ID (they do have a procedure for this) 2) pay off someone to get you a 24 hour passport.

Comment: @user568458 - I'm half asking because I think it's a good question and maybe it can get me lots of rep points lol :D But a friend of mine also did lose their ID and has an upcoming trip more than a month away. Hopefully that's plenty of time but who knows. But rather then getting caught up on details of the specific incident I figure the generic question is more interesting.

Comment: There are other hypotheticals that are less contrived: (1) You forgot your ID at home -- my wife did this once and (2) your wallet including DL and other picture IDs was lost or stolen while you were traveling to the airport.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate question, but the same answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68863/19400

Comment: @phoog - I think a wallet being stolen whilst in transit is pretty contrived. You get up, get packed, and while driving to the airport in your personal automobile someone steals your wallet? Who's gonna have the chance to steal your wallet? A ghost? In contrast, let's say you went to a bar a week before your big trip and your wallet was stolen then. The number of suspects goes up considerably. And most of them are going to basically be untrackable strangers to you.

Comment: I've gotten a replacement license at the Maryland MVA in about seven minutes after waking in the door. In Virginia when you complete an online renewal or address change you get the new license in about a week. I'm sure it's faster if you go into an actual DMV. So as a hypothetical this needs a hypothetical state since the response time for a replacement license probably varies greatly. In particular I'd expect California and DC to take more time than Maryland and Virginia. I'm pretty sure if my wallet were stolen Monday I'd have all my cards again by Friday.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox - good idea. I've updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: @neubert first, I said *lost or* stolen. Second, many people don't drive themselves to the airport because parking is too expensive or because, like me, they do not own a car. Pickpockets typically concentrate on trains and other public transportation serving airports because of the high percentage of tourists. A wallet can fall out of your pocket in a taxi. These scenarios also tend to leave you in a position where you are unlikely to recover your wallet, at least before your flight.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Call the airline to see if they have any suggestions.

[TSA does not *require* you to have ID:](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification)

> In the event you arrive at the airport without valid identification,
>   because it is lost or at home, you may still be allowed to fly. The
>   TSA officer may ask you to complete a form to include your name and
>   current address, and may ask additional questions to confirm your
>   identity. If your identity is confirmed, you will be allowed to enter
>   the screening checkpoint. You may be subject to additional screening.
>
> You will not be allowed to fly if your identity cannot be confirmed,
>   you chose to not provide proper identification or you decline to
>   cooperate with the identity verification process.

Comment: Ah I was just going to add this to my answer, too slow !

Comment: What pull does the airline have with TSA?  TSA doesn't treat passengers differently based on the airline they are flying on,

Comment: @cdkMoose, I would expect the airline to be asked a question like this often, and therefore have already found the answer.  And, just a hunch, they might be more helpful than the TSA.

Comment: @donjuedo, all true, but in the end, they are not the authoritative resource, so getting their advice doesn't mean it will work.  While the TSA may be less helpful, if they tell you what to do, then you have your  answer.

Comment: @cdkMoose I only said that because you make the booking with the airline, not the airport nor the TSA. It would be silly not to alert the airline of your predicament when you have opportunity to do so. If you can't get on the plane because you don't have any ID, then it really becomes the airline's problem, not TSA's.

Comment: @HarryVervet, understood and you are correct if you don't eventually get on.  I viewed this as a question of how do I get through TSA, not what can I do if I don't.  You are correct that the problem would shift to the airline, but they may not care since they have your money and they didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: Why not comply if you're not a criminal?

Comment: The process isn't that complicated, apparently. I just went through it twice. Sure, they used every security scan available to them, including the full body scan plus pat down plus the swabs of your gear, but the inconvenience isn't that bad as long as you cooperate.

Comment: This was my experience too, flying home after I'd lost my license. They basically had me show them everything in my wallet, and by the time I got to my museum membership cards, they were convinced. Although it's possible that you may have a harder time depending on how you look, your ethnicity, etc.

Answer (score 9):

There are many other ways to provide ID to security, depending on how many of those were also stolen with your wallet, you have quite a few options.

According to the TSA's [website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), you can use any of the following (besides your driver's license and passport):

> - U.S. passport card
> - DHS trusted traveler cards (Global Entry, NEXUS, SENTRI, FAST)
> - U.S. military ID (active duty or retired military and their dependents, and DoD civilians)
> - Permanent resident card
> - Border crossing card
> - DHS-designated enhanced driver's license
> - Airline or airport-issued ID (if issued under a TSA-approved security plan)
> - Federally recognized, tribal-issued photo ID
> - HSPD-12 PIV card
> - Foreign government-issued passport
> - Canadian provincial driver's license or Indian and Northern Affairs Canada card
> - Transportation worker identification credential
> - Immigration and Naturalization Service Employment Authorization Card (I-766)

Note however that weapon permits and temporary driver's license are **not** an acceptable form of identification.

Of course, as [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74111/9551) answer mentions, you can still travel if you have no ID.

Comment: I wonder what percentage of the US population has any one of thsoe documents.  I imagine it's pretty small.

Comment: @phoog Nexus/Gloabl entry, PR cards, foreign passports and military IDs should be pretty common. I skipped US passport in that list because the OP assumes he has none

Comment: Between passports, military ID (which includes military family members, so that's a lot more people), a couple million Global Entry members, a decent number of Enhanced Driver's Licenses from the states that issue them, I'd say a fairly good chunk of people have at least one of those documents. And since the TSA will usually work with you if you have no ID, it's even less of an issue.

Comment: @ZachLipton we're talking about alternative ID when the DL is lost or stolen, so enhanced DLs don't count.  The military seems to be around 3 million, so maybe there are 10 to 15 million military IDs running around; there are a similar number of green cards.  Even if we assume no overlap, that's around 10% of the country.  Is 10% "pretty common"?

Comment: @phoog I meant the most common types of ID from that list

Comment: The relevant metric is really "percent of people who might want to fly," not just percent of the whole country, so that changes things, but also makes it harder to measure. Anyway, around [36%](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit0suK34fOAhVQyWMKHZtKAD4QFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmic.com%2Farticles%2F28780%2Fwhy-64-of-americans-have-never-left-the-u-s&usg=AFQjCNEClBDqEDgzhZ8mc5nVO_B5IOyBUg&sig2=5sXqlUoIvUshO76_outehw) have a valid passport.

Comment: Kind of odd that they consider a weapons permit less secure than a foreign D/L.

Comment: I wouldn't count Global Entry members.  Why in the world would someone have Global Entry but no passport?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany do they? In my experience they are rather dismissive of foreign driver's licenses (aside from Canadian ones, which they apparently accept).

Comment: @phoog Those are the foreign ones of which I speak. For what it's worth a (Canadian) firearm licence is accepted as a travel document for domestic Canadian travel, same as a D/L or other government ID.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just go to the local Department of Motor Vehicles (or equivalent in your state) office and get a replacement.  They are aware that these things happen and have forms for just this case.

I recently misplaced my license and followed this course.  I waited in line for 10 minutes and the process took about 5.  I think there may have been a small replacement fee.

Not only will this help with your travel plans, but you're going to need a new copy anyway.

Comment: idk how it works in other states but in TX the way it works is...  you go to the Department of Public Safety and you'll get a temporary paper ID on the spot. The more permanent ID will be snail mailed to you. You don't get a fancy full color ID with all the security features until several weeks later.

Comment: @neubert temporary driver's license aren't accepted though

Comment: @blackbird57 - I know. I just mentioned them because, in TX, at least, that's what you get the day you get your picture taken, regardless of whether or not that's what you need. Maybe in other states it's different but in TX you can't just go "this piece of paper is useless junk! I need a real ID that's suitable for my purposes and I need it /right now/!"

Comment: Interesting, since you need your license to drive anyway.  You would think they would establish a process to quickly give you a valid drivers license.  Maybe that is just expecting too much from the government :)  In NJ, I was given a new permanent drivers license on the spot.

Comment: Actually, in TX, you can even use a court order as a license lol. Like a temporary license at least has a pic even if it's black and white. A court order doesn't even have that. Quoting https://www.txdps.state.tx.us/DriverLicense/OccupationalLicense.htm, "*The court order may be used as a driver license for 45 days from the date of the judge’s signature while the request for an occupational license is processed*"

Comment: I believe the federal "RealID" standards mean that any state in compliance with them cannot give same-day valid IDs - only temporary ones that won't be acceptable.

Comment: @cdkMoose, it depends on what you mean by "valid license".  When I did a change of address, the receipt from my visit to the DMV was considered legally valid proof that I was allowed to drive on public roads, but I'm pretty sure the TSA wouldn't accept it as a form of identification.  The actual updated license (ie. the thing the TSA *would* accept) didn't arrive for another week.

Comment: @Mark , OPs scenario is lost, not changed

Comment: @cdkMoose, my point is that there are different sorts of "valid" when it comes to a driver's license.

Comment: The paper is valid for driving (where the cop can look up the records), it's not photo ID and therefore not acceptable to the TSA.  And is there anyplace that still actually issues you the photo ID rather than mailing it?  The latter is a security step in verifying the address.

Answer (score 4):

Harry Vervet's answer is correct, as someone that flies quite a bit, I can tell you 100% your don't need a state issued ID to fly.

What you should do is allow your self more time to get through the process. 9/10 times they just send you through the perv scanner and ask a few extra questions. Some airports are setup in a way that the boarding pass check and the security check point are very far apart, in those cases you don't even (usually) need to show your ID at the security check point, just the boarding pass check.

Now there are two important things that you should know. (and it's why I made this a separate answer)

1. If you bought your ticket with a credit card, and intend to pick it up at the desk at the airport, this usually requires an ID or the credit card used to make the purchase. This has nothing to do with TSA though and every airline will have different rules about this.
2. When you get your boarding pass from the airline counter, if you tell them you don't have your ID, then can (at least at some airports) provide you with a "pass" to get you past the boarding checkpoint. It's a little piece of paper that they staple to your boarding pass. This tells TSA that you don't have an ID and that the airline verified your identity some how.  Usually TSA will ask you extra questions, and may flag you as needing more then just the metal detector. Some airline can even issue you a temporary ID, that works just fine for TSA. It's worth asking the airline, and working with them.

Comment: Your point 1 seems completely wrong. At every airport I've used for domestic flights in the past few years, all the airlines have self-check-in, and all you need to know to check in and get boarding passes is the alphanumeric (usually 5-character) booking identifier they gave you.

Comment: @R.. Depends, Usually if you buy online, you get this booking number. If you purchase over the phone or via some travel agents, or a few other methods that require you to go to the airport to pick up your ticket (this is different then a boarding pass) then you have to present your payment.

Comment: A good example of this is, if you plan a flight days-weeks in advance, then you buy online and get an e-ticket. This e-ticket is all you ever get till you get your boarding pass. If you purchase a "same day" ticket on the phone in the cab on the way to the airport, or a short notice ticket by calling the airline and purchasing a ticket for tomorrow then you usually have to pickup that ticket up at the counter and present your payment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can't imagine wanting to do that (when I've needed a last-minute ticket purchase, I used the airline's website from my phone) so I didn't even think of it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering why you just don't drive to your nearest MVS office and get a replacement on the spot. Also, why are you even asking here. Call your airline for info directly related to your specific situation. I lost my license while on vacation and didn't realize it until I was ready to go through airport security. (I had already printed my boarding pass at the hotel.) I was allowed to fly back home after being 'grilled' for about half an hour.