# Can I travel without valid ID if I am registered with TSA PreCheck?

Tags: usa, paperwork, tsa, lost-documents

US domestic flight. I lost my passport and my flight is in 2 weeks. I have IDs like Student ID, but no other government ID. I am registered with TSA PreCheck though. Would it be possible to still fly without valid government ID, if they can compare fingerprints/do some other sort of check?

Edit: I also have a photo of the passport.

Comment: Whilst not an exact duplicate, this should answer your question - [Can I travel with my USA expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68863/can-i-travel-with-my-usa-expired-passport)

Comment: Two weeks might be enough time to get a state ID card, assuming you're eligible for one.  Not having other ID might make that process trickier, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such policy in the PreCheck program itself, as far as I know.

The TSA does have procedures for checking people who don't have valid ID, see https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification:

> In the event you arrive at the airport without valid identification, because it is lost or at home, you may still be allowed to fly. The TSA officer may ask you to complete an identity verification process which includes collecting information such as your name, current address, and other personal information to confirm your identity. If your identity is confirmed, you will be allowed to enter the screening checkpoint. You will be subject to additional screening, to include a patdown and screening of carry-on property.
>
> You will not be allowed to enter the security checkpoint if your identity cannot be confirmed, you choose to not provide proper identification or you decline to cooperate with the identity verification process.
>
> TSA recommends that you arrive at least two hours in advance of your flight time.

This doesn't directly have anything to do with PreCheck, though it's possible that being registered will make it easier for them to verify your identity.  Even so, allow plenty of extra time, and understand there is a risk that they may not be satisfied with your identity and refuse to let you fly.  And even after your identity is verified, I suspect you will not be allowed to go through the expedited PreCheck screening.

Comment: I must say I am surprised by that. Without ID, how can they verify (e.g.) no-fly?

Comment: @CGCampbell: I assume they use databases to verify you are who you claim.  If you say your name is X, does the personal data you provide match what their databases say about X?  Maybe they have photos of X on file from driver's license or passport databases, etc.  And once they are satisfied that you really are X, then they can check that X is not on any no-fly list, just as they would if you had shown an ID with the name X.