# ID required at the time I pick up my airline ticket

Tags: air-travel, usa, tsa, domestic-travel, identity-cards

I'll be traveling to Dallas TX, but I'm still waiting for the state of Illinois to send me my hard copy of my driver's license all they gave me was a piece of paper with my picture on it. Can I still fly?

Comment: I have my VA ID, which is a government ID. Can I use that?

Comment: Do you mean a photo ID from the state of Virginia or one from the Veterans Administration?

Comment: I have an ID Issued By The Veterans Administration, will that be acceptable?

Comment: A Veterans Administration ID is, unfortunately, not acceptable to the TSA. A [retired military ID](http://www.cac.mil/uniformed-services-id-card/), if you have one, is acceptable. I would bring your VA ID though, as it will help the TSA verify your identity, but you'll likely have to go through the extra verification checks.

Comment: A Veteran Administration ID is a Federal ID, I've even cashed a check in a bank before using that ID when I lost my wallet. I will bring it though with birth certificate, my DD214, and my expired license, and debit card with my name on it. It looks like Our Government and TSA has made it More difficult for us citizens.

Comment: Oh, you have your expired license? My understanding is that they'll accept an expired license, no questions asked, if it's been expired [for less than a year](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53823/can-a-person-in-the-usa-fly-with-an-expired-driving-license), though that's not an official policy on their website about this. You should be fine in any case, especially with the expired license, with maybe just a delay for some extra checks if the license is more than a year expired.

Answer (score 6):

The [TSA's requirements](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) list various forms of acceptable identification. However:

> A temporary driver's license is not an acceptable form of identification.

If you have one of the other documents on that list, you're all set.

If not, [you can attempt to fly without ID](http://blog.tsa.gov/2013/04/tsa-travel-tips-tuesday-can-you-fly.html):

> If you’re willing to provide some additional information, we have
>   other means of substantiating your identity, such as using publicly
>   available databases. If we can confirm your identity, you’ll be
>   cleared to go through security, and you may or may not have to go
>   through some additional screening.
>
> If we can’t confirm your identity with the information you provide or
>   you’re not willing to provide us with the information to help us make
>   a determination, you may not be able to fly. Regardless, if you do not
>   have ID, please allow extra time for check in. We would not want you
>   to miss you flight.

The process will take extra time and will require some personal information. They'll ask you some security questions, and if they're able to verify your identity, you'll be allowed through, usually with extra screening. If you have other forms of identification, such as other forms of photo ID the TSA doesn't normally accept (even a Costco or Sam's Club card if you have one), it wouldn't hurt to bring them along. This procedure is not guaranteed, and you could be refused if they can't verify your identity.

If possible, I'd check in online, so at least you have your boarding pass without being asked to show ID.