# I have to send out my passport for visa processing, can I fly with my expired driver's license and a photocopy of my passport

Tags: air-travel, domestic-travel, identity-cards, us-residents

What it says on the tin: I'm a U.S. national adult and I need to send my passport out for visa processing this week. On August 10, I'm flying to San Francisco from Chicago and my passport is the only currently valid form of id I have.

Will I be able to get away with using my (expired) driver's license in combination with a photocopy of my passport?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE; please see *[Can a person in the USA fly with an expired driving license?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53823/can-a-person-in-the-usa-fly-with-an-expired-driving-license)* The short answer is no: neither an expired ID nor a photocopy of an ID are acceptable. You will likely be directed to follow the instructions under the "Forgot Your ID?" section of the TSA's [Identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) page.

Comment: You have more than two weeks - that might be enough time to renew your driver's license if you hurry.

Answer (score 0):

The "REAL ID" FAQ says any state driver's license, *for now*.  Doesn't say "unexpired"--I don't know whether that should always be assumed or not.  The expiration technically refers to your driving privilege.  It's still good ID.  But we all know TSA doesn't always make sense.

See [this](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) for other options.

Comment: Your "this" link says (emphasis added) "must show **valid** identification."