# Will my NYC Learner's Permit allow me to travel domestically without a passport?

Tags: new-york-city, domestic-travel, portland

I'm travelling from NYC to Oregon on the 20th of June, and just now I checked my passport and realized it had expired in April. If I want to renew my passport, I either have to wait 8 weeks or more to get it done without paying, or pay over 100 dollars to get it expedited.

My question is: I have a learner's permit issued by the state of New York. Can I use that in place of a passport when travelling?

Comment: There's a list of acceptable ID at the [TSA web site](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification). If your learner's permit is a photo ID you might be in luck.

Comment: The TSA is [generally ok with expired ID](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53823/can-a-person-in-the-usa-fly-with-an-expired-driving-license) if it's recently expired, so your passport that expired in April is likely acceptable even if the learner's permit does not qualify.